# Make Fragment Grows and Show More Info

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

my application have 2 fragments:

1 - Have several fields to insert info for a query, and initially it shows only a field to input the name and a button that make it grows;

2 - A list view that would show the results for the query.

I'm using Visibility.GONE to make the trick (not show the other fields, and when the user press the button, they appear):

I have several of these

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.tcgapp.myrium.fowhelper.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/fragment_search_area"
>
<!--android:background="#c94040" -->
<!-- Name of Card and button to expand the view-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/layout_name_search"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/label_name"
        android:text="@string/name_label"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_name"
        android:hint="@string/name_hint"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.90" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_expand"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_downward_black_24dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Type Set and Format-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/search_tags_area"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <util.MultiSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_rarity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <util.MultiSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_set"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_format"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Card Text Field-->
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edit_card_text"
    android:hint="@string/field_text"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

<!-- Spinners-->
<!-- Attribute and choices-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/layout_attribute"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <util.MultiSpinner
        android:id="@+id/multi_spinner_attribute"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_choices_to_query_attribute"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Now the query fields-->
<!-- Atk Def-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_atkdef"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#75b194"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_atk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/field_atk"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_atk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"/>

    <!-- Atk field-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_def"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/field_def"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_def"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- SubType and CMC-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_subtype_cmc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#75b194"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/field_subtype"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/field_cmc"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_cmc"/>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Card Flavor e Code-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_flavor_code"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#75b194"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_card_flavor"
        android:hint="@string/field_flavor"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_card_code"
        android:hint="@string/field_code"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And on Java code, i have an animator object, and this is its AnimationEnd():

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int newWeight = isExpanded ? 0 : 60;

        ViewWeightAnimationWrapper animationWrapper = new ViewWeightAnimationWrapper(getView());
        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animationWrapper,
                "weight",
                animationWrapper.getWeight(),
                newWeight);
        anim.setDuration(500);
        anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationStart(animation);
//                if (!isExpanded){
//                    getView().findViewById(R.id.layout_atkdef).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//                    getView().findViewById(R.id.layout_subtype_cmc).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//                    getView().findViewById(R.id.layout_attribute).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//                    getView().findViewById(R.id.layout_flavor_code).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//                }
            }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd (Animator animation){
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    if (isExpanded) {
                        imageButtonToggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_downward_black_24dp);
                        getView().findViewById(R.id.layout_atkdef).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        getView().findViewById(R.id.layout_subtype_cmc).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        getView().findViewById(R.id.layout_attribute).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        getView().findViewById(R.id.layout_flavor_code).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        imageButtonToggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_upward_black_24dp);
                        getView().findViewById(R.id.layout_atkdef).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        getView().findViewById(R.id.layout_subtype_cmc).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        getView().findViewById(R.id.layout_attribute).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        getView().findViewById(R.id.layout_flavor_code).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                }
            }
            );
            anim.start();
        }
    }
```

This is the way to hide the fields and show only when the user presses the expand button, or is a better way?

UPDATE: Providing full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're asking if there's a nicer way of expanding/hiding an area with input, I'll share my implementation using your variables as best I can. I'll make some necessary notes as well.

```
//consider changing imageButtonToggle to a container view with an image in it
//in this example I'll use carrotImage as the image contained within imageButtonToggle
//formContainer contains all the views you're toggling from GONE to VISIBLE.
imageButtonToggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isExpanded) {
                    ViewAnimationHelper
                            .expand(formContainer, 300, false);
                } else {
                    ViewAnimationHelper.collapse(formContainer, 300);
                }

                carrotImage.animate().rotation(ROTATION_COUNT);

                ROTATION_COUNT += 180f;
                //Silly check.. but better safe than sorry.
                if (ROTATION_COUNT >= Float.MAX_VALUE)
                    ROTATION_COUNT = 0f;

                isExpanded= !isExpanded;
            }
    });


public class ViewAnimationHelper {

/**
 * Easy way to expand a given view after measuring with
 * v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 * 
 * @param v
 * @param duration
 */
public static void expand(final View v, int duration,
        boolean bStartFromZeroHeight) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    if (bStartFromZeroHeight)
        v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;

    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1 ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration(duration);
    v.startAnimation(a);
}

/**
 * Easy way to just collapse any given view and any given speed
 * 
 * @param v
 * @param duration
 */
public static void collapse(final View v, int duration) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                Transformation t) {
            if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight
                        - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration(duration);
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm testing here and it's really cool! I'm trying your code here, also I will update this question with my XML. But my problem would be with show only  few fields (the search by name), and after pressing the button, the other fields would appear.

Comment: I managed to make the animation I wanted just finding each layout and giving to the animation. Also, no waste of space (this was happening, because i wasn't able to figure out how to get the exact height). Thanks a lot!

Also, if possible, can you provide the tutorial or source that gave yout he idea for this implementation?

I'm trying to understand, since the visibility is set to GONE or visible before the animation. It doesn't make the view appear or disappear at once.